# Insert SQL data to Excel using PHPSpreadsheet

Tags: sql, phpspreadsheet

Is it possible to insert sql data to excel using PHPSpreadsheet?

something like this...

```
$var= $row['name'] // data from database
$rowArray = ['$var', 'Value2', 'Value3', 'Value4'];
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
->fromArray(
    $rowArray,   // The data to set
    NULL,        // Array values with this value will not be set
    'C3'         // Top left coordinate of the worksheet range where
                 //    we want to set these values (default is A1)
);
```

i've already tried this but the value is not inserted in the cell.

Please help!